# Unable to connect web3.js on my localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

Here is my project details:
I am building simple project to store data from form to Ethereum blockchain.
I have install nodejs, web3 using npm.
I am using web version 4.3.0.

I am using Ganache for local environment but unable to import ETH to metamask on chrome. I added manually network still showing 0 ETH.

For contract I have used remix.ethereum.org. (this is done.)
Unable to run my project on localhost (XAMPP)

here are my code:

for Index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Waste Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Waste Management System</h1>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <label for="wasteType">Waste Type:</label>
        <input type="text" id="wasteType" name="wasteType" required><br>

        <label for="weight">Weight:</label>
        <input type="number" id="weight" name="weight" required><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <!--script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@4.3.0/lib/commonjs/web3.min.js"></script-->
    <script type="module" src="interact.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

For process.php

```
<?php
// process.php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Retrieve form data
    $wasteType = $_POST["wasteType"];
    $weight = $_POST["weight"];

    // Perform any necessary processing or validation

    // Redirect to success.php
    header("Location: success.php");
    exit();
} else {
    // Invalid request method
    echo "Invalid request method";
}
?>
```

for success.php

```
<!-- success.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Success</title>
    <!--script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@4.3.0/lib/commonjs/web3.min.js"></script-->
     <script type="module" src="interact.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Waste Records</h2>

    <?php
    // Check if the data has been successfully added
    if (isset($_GET['success'])) {
        if ($_GET['success'] == 'true') {
            echo '<p style="color: green;">Waste data added successfully!</p>';
        } elseif ($_GET['success'] == 'false') {
            echo '<p style="color: red;">Failed to add waste data. Please try again.</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>

    <a href="index.html">Back to Form</a>

    <table id="wasteTable">
        <tr>
            <th>User</th> 
            <th>Waste Type</th>
            <th>Weight</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        // Fetch waste records and update the table
        async function fetchWasteRecords() {
            const response = await fetch('/getWasteRecords');
            const records = await response.json();

            const table = document.getElementById('wasteTable');
            records.forEach(record => {
                const row = table.insertRow(-1);
                const userCell = row.insertCell(0);
                const wasteTypeCell = row.insertCell(1);
                const weightCell = row.insertCell(2);
                const timestampCell = row.insertCell(3);

                userCell.textContent = record.user;
                wasteTypeCell.textContent = record.wasteType;
                weightCell.textContent = record.weight;
                timestampCell.textContent = new Date(record.timestamp * 1000).toLocaleString();
            });
        }

        // Call the function when the page loads
        fetchWasteRecords();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

for interact.js

```
// interact.js

import Web3 from 'web3.js';

// Connect to your Ethereum node
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545'); // Update with your Ethereum node URL

// Check if connected to the Ethereum node
if (web3 && web3.currentProvider && web3.currentProvider.connected) {
    console.log('Connected to Ethereum node:', web3.currentProvider.host);
} else {
    console.error('Failed to connect to Ethereum node. Please check your node URL.');
    process.exit(1); // Exit the script with an error code
}

console.log('Connecting to Ethereum node...');

const contractAddress = 'MY_contract_address'; // Replace with your deployed contract address
const contractABI = [
    
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "user",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "wasteType",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "weight",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "WasteAdded",
        "type": "event"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_wasteType",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "_weight",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addWasteData",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "wasteCount",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "wasteRecords",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "user",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "wasteType",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "weight",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

// Initialize the contract instance
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

// Get form data from index.html
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const wasteType = document.getElementById('wasteType').value;
    const weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

    // Get the first account (you may need to handle accounts differently in production)
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    // Call the addWasteData function on the smart contract
    await contract.methods.addWasteData(wasteType, weight).send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // Redirect to success.php with a success parameter
    window.location.href = 'success.php?success=true';
});
```

Error I am getting on console:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "web3.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".